# WindowsForm application generates a console application in visual studio

Tags: windows, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I am currently developing a winform application in .Net using visual studio 2013.

My issue is when I compile my app I get both a console app and winform app in my `bin` directory and the winform.exe does not launch unless the console.exe is present.

The console.exe is an app from a separate project which uses the same classes as the winform app.

How can I get rid of this dependency ?

Comment: if you want to have common code between the apps, you need 3 projects. a winforms, a console, and a Class Library type project, which will generate a .dll file containing the common code.

Comment: that was it, could you post an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which uses the same classes as the WinForm app

Well, that's a bit of a mess of course.  And it is not accurate, your winforms app in fact uses at least one class from your console app project.

First thing you need to do is to *remove* the project reference from your winforms app project.  Open its References node, locate the console project, right-click and select Remove.  You have now broken the dependency.  But it won't compile anymore, the error messages tells you how much trouble is ahead.

Next thing you need to do is add a new class library project.  It should contain all the types that both the console project and the winforms project need.  Add a project reference to this new project.  And move the code.

If this all entirely too much work or you can't unravel the dependencies anymore then not changing anything is an entirely acceptable shortcut.  A console app can also act as a class library, the CLR doesn't have a problem with it.  You in general avoid getting into this mess by not blindingly declare classes public.  If you think it *needs* to be public then it typically belongs in a class library project.